# In a multi-monitor display environment, how do I tell Selenium which display to open a new window in?

Tags: selenium

Sorry if this has been asked and answered.  I did a search but came up empty.

Comment: Is this question for Windows or Mac?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is very useful for debugging to run tests on a secondary monitor. Unfortunately you cannot specify on which monitor browser should be opened. The options are:

1. Open browser and drag it to the desired monitor, then close it. Next time it will be opened on that monitor
2. Use software like [Ultramon](http://www.realtimesoft.com/ultramon/) to control on which monitor to start browser.

Also you can use a virtual machine that will be run on the second monitor - just drag it there.

Comment: My SUT (system under test) opens a new window at certain points in my test scenario.  I have three monitors and I wanted to send it to a different monitor.  Oh well.  The technique that I finally settled on for forcing which monitor the app opens in is to use my Macbook's System Preferences -> display to set which window is the main window.  It was defaulting to my laptop (too small) and everytime a window would pop it would pop there.  By making one of my large displays the main window, everything now pops there.  Thank you for answers.

Comment: This answer may not work all the time. Especially when you are changing monitors (work to home, system restart etc). Below answers are better than the accepted answer.

PS: I have posted my solution below

Answer (score 17):

In python:

```
browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.set_window_position(2000, 0)
```

Comment: This also works well in C#.  I use:  options.AddArguments("window-position=-2000,0");  then driver.Manage().Window.Maximize(); to put the Chrome on my left monitor.

Answer (score 16):

There's actually a fairly easy way to do this. There's a method called 'set_window_position' which accepts negative values. So I wanted the browser to open on my left screen, so a simple negative 1000px pixels dragged it in enough for the maximize_window to pick the left screen.

```
driver.set_window_position(-1000, 0)
driver.maximize_window()
```

So depending on the screen sizes and where you want it to go, make some calculations and just drag it there!

Source: http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#module-selenium.webdriver.firefox.webdriver (picked firefox for this example)

Answer (score 14):

Two options (this is for the [coypu](/questions/tagged/coypu) [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23) wrapper):

1. Use the Selenium Driver's window positioning commands:

   ```cs
   var monitor = Screen.FromPoint(new Point(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Right + 1, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Top));

   var seleniumDriver = new ChromeDriver(options);
   seleniumDriver.Manage().Window.Position = new Point(monitor.Bounds.X, monitor.Bounds.Y);

   var coypuDriver = new MultimonWebDriver(seleniumDriver, Browser.Chrome);
   var rv = new BrowserSession(sessionConfiguration, coypuDriver);
   ```
2. Configure the Driver with a command line argument.  I prefer this because solution #1 causes a flicker from the driver's server showing the window before processing the move command:

   ```cs
   var monitor = Screen.FromPoint(new Point(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Right + 1, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Top));

   var options = new ChromeOptions();
   options.AddArgument(String.Format("--window-position={0},{1}", monitor.Bounds.X, monitor.Bounds.Y));

   var seleniumDriver = new ChromeDriver(options);
   var coypuDriver = new MultimonWebDriver(seleniumDriver, Browser.Chrome);
   var rv = new BrowserSession(sessionConfiguration, coypuDriver);
   ```

where MultimonWebDriver is simply exposing access to the protected constructor:

```cs
public class MultimonWebDriver : SeleniumWebDriver
{
  public MultimonWebDriver(IWebDriver webDriver, Browser browser) : base(webDriver, browser)
  {
  }
}
```

Answer (score 9):

In OSX Mavericks you can assign desktop from the Options menu when clicking and holding the icon from the dock. This solved the problem for me.

Comment: You are a lifesaver.

Comment: In other words, the monitor that has the dock is the default monitor, and it's where the Selenium browser will open by default.

Answer (score 6):

I use this not very fancy, but quick method to achieve that. Because I do not only want it on my second screen but also maximized I don't have to be too precise on the coordinates. Any X-coordinate above 2000 is usually on the second screen for all my dev machines: (This example uses chromedriver but works with any IWebDriver)

```
chrome = new ChromeDriver();
chrome.Manage().Window.Position = new System.Drawing.Point(2000, 1); // To 2nd monitor. 
chrome.Manage().Window.Maximize();
```

Answer (score 6):

Wailord's answer worked for me but it always opened the window and then moved it. So there is a brief moment where it blocks my editor.

Chrome has a command-line switch for window position
`--window-position=x,y`
https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/#window-position

```
from selenium import webdriver
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('window-position=2000,0')  # opens at x=2000,y=0 from the start
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
```

Comment: This should probably be the accepted answer as OP seems to be trying to perform this on new-window creation, and other answers are moving the window starting on the wrong monitor to a different one.

Answer (score 4):

I have 2 1920x1080 monitors, I move the browser window to the 2nd monitor and maximize it there.

1. Get screen resolution

   ```
   java.awt.Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
   double width = screenSize.getWidth();
   double height = screenSize.getHeight();
   ```
2. Move browser to second monitor and maximize

   ```
   if (width <= 1920) {
       Point point = new Point(width, 0);
       driver.manage().window().setPosition(point);
       driver.manage().window().maximize();
   }
   ```
3. If your resolution is wider than a typical monitor, open the browser in a more realistic resolution (this is optional, but I recommend it)

   ```
   else 

   {
       Point point = new Point(0, 0);
       driver.manage().window().setPosition(point);

       Dimension targetWindowSize = new Dimension(1920, 1080);
       driver.manage().window().setSize(targetWindowSize);
   }
   ```

Answer (score 2):

use this condiction:

```
WebDriver chrome1 = new ChromeDriver();
WebDriver chrome2 = new ChromeDriver();

chrome1.manage().window().maximize();//display 1

chrome2.manage().window().setPosition(new Point(2000,0));//display 2
Thread.sleep(1000);// 1 sec
chrome2.manage().window().maximize();//maximize display 2
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are running Windows 7 or later, you can (hack-ishly) achieve this by setting the desired display as your main display under "Change Display Settings". Any new browser windows will now open in this one. Keep in main that this of course affects your toolbar etc, which may or may not be annoying. It is certainly less annoying than having browser windows thrown in your face on a steady basis.

Answer (score 1):

On Mac you can control this in `System Preferences > Displays > Arrangement`

There is a white bar at the top of the primary screen. Drag it to the screen where you want the browsers to be rendered

Answer (score 0):

My solution is install an VNC server, open the VNC in one of the monitors and launch selenium through the VNC.
Then you have always one monitor for the browsers of selenium without the annoying windows opened each time a test is launched

Answer (score 0):

For **Java**:

```
//imports:
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.InputEvent;

driver = new FirefoxDriver();

//drag & drop to my right screen in debug mode:
boolean isDebug = java.lang.management.ManagementFactory.getRuntimeMXBean().getInputArguments().toString().indexOf("jdwp") >= 0;

if(isDebug) {
  Robot robot = new Robot();

  robot.mouseMove(800, 10);
  robot.mousePress(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
  robot.mouseMove(2800, 100);
  robot.mouseRelease(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
  driver.manage().window().maximize();
}
```

`driver.manage().window().setPosition(point);` didn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

I have noticed that by setting these things below, my browser gets opened alway in the same monitor (I have two monitors the eDP and a secondary HDMI monitor). Maybe it has to do with the position:

```
# console log
d = desired_capabilities.DesiredCapabilities.CHROME
d['loggingPrefs'] = { 'browser':'ALL' }

# Driver
self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(desired_capabilities=d)
self.driver.implicitly_wait(5) # seconds
self.driver.set_window_size(800, 800)
self.driver.set_window_position(0, 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that for me its always opening in the primary monitor. So I changed the primary display from OSX display arrangement options window.

Answer (score 0):

In case the monitor where you want to open a browser windows is to the *left* of the monitor with IDE, try negative values. In Java:

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.manage().window().setPosition(new Point(-1500, 0));
```

Answer (score 0):

Just put the Mac "Menu Bar" on the monitor where you want the browser to open up.    That sets the default monitor.

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround for this which in my case worked for me in Windows 10. I just simply made my second monitor as the Main Display via Display Settings:

[Main Display via Display Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oXZkS.png)

Hope this helps you as well!

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using this in Java, and it's working

```
public void maximizeToNextMonitor(WebDriver driver, String server) {
    driver.get(server);
    Window window = driver.manage().window();
    window.maximize();
    window.setPosition(new org.openqa.selenium.Point(window.getSize().getWidth(), 0));
    window.maximize();
}
```