# Selenium-opening browser in different screen

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to open Selenium in a different screen rather than the main screen and in maximum size. I tried

```
browser.set_window_position(2000, 0)
browser.maximize_window()
```

But it opens the browser in main window first and then moves it to the different window. I found the following command in

[In a multi-monitor display environment, how do I tell Selenium which display to open a new window in?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3816073/in-a-multi-monitor-display-environment-how-do-i-tell-selenium-which-display-to/32418159)

```
var monitor = Screen.FromPoint(new Point(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Right + 1, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Top));

var options = new ChromeOptions();
options.AddArgument(String.Format("--window-position={0},{1}", monitor.Bounds.X, monitor.Bounds.Y));

var seleniumDriver = new ChromeDriver(options);
var coypuDriver = new MultimonWebDriver(seleniumDriver, Browser.Chrome);
var rv = new BrowserSession(sessionConfiguration, coypuDriver);
```

But it is in c#. Can anybody please help me out with the python version of it?

Comment: Moves into different window or different monitor ?

Comment: move to a different monitor.

Answer (score 8):

use Chrome Options to set the defaults

```
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--window-position=2000,0")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)
```

There are various options you can add like `chrome_options.add_argument("--start-maximized");`

Answer (score 0):

With reference to Ywapom's comment, if your 'other' display is on the left, use a negative pixel number to move the window there, e.g. `--window-position=-1600,100`