# How to choose which monitor Robot Framework will display test execution?

Tags: selenium, selenium-chromedriver, robotframework

I'm currently working with 2 monitors, and I've noticed that Robot Framework (using SeleniumLibrary) always open the test execution in the main display that is selected in windows display settings.

Is there any way to choose which monitor will be used to display test execution?

This is how I'm starting the browser. I'm currently using Chrome

```
Start Browser
    Open Browser        ${url}              ${BROWSER}      
    ...  options=add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-logging"])
    Maximize Browser Window
```

Comment: Seems like you cannot specify on which monitor browser should be opened. 
take a look at [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3816073/in-a-multi-monitor-display-environment-how-do-i-tell-selenium-which-display-to](link)

Comment: I don't think this is specific to robot framework. It's probably a feature or limitation of webdriver.

Comment: I've researched and found that we can make it work with this in python:

`browser.set_window_position(2000, 0)`

But I couldn't make it work for Robot Framework

Answer (score 0):

Ragnoroct's answer here seems to be a solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57545639/16635196.

> Chrome has a command-line switch for window position
> --window-position=x,y
> https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/#window-position

```
from selenium import webdriver
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('window-position=2000,0')  # opens at x=2000,y=0 from the start
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
```

Since I was not using Python directly in the Robot tests, I resorted to directly modifying the Python package source where these options are set. For example, *AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\QWeb\internal\browser\chrome.py* for combination of QWeb and Windows10. Obviously not a good way of doing things in the long run, but virtual environment could be of help here.

*Start-maximized* didn't work in conjunction with *window-position*, so I had to additionally use *window-size=2560,1440*.