# Start chromedriver on another screen with maximized window

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, chrome-options

I want to start the chromedriver my second screen, but in a maximized window.
Currently, I'm doing this after already the driver has already been initialized:

```
driver.Manage().Window.Position = Screen.AllScreens[myDisplayNumber].Bounds.Location;
driver.Manage().Window.Maximize();
```

But while I'm fixing the error mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48450594/selenium-timed-out-receiving-message-from-renderer), I am now using the ChromeOptions to set the window maximized.
To start the browser on my other screen, I tried the '--window-position'-argument.
The thing is, it just doesn't work in combination with the '--start-maximized' argument.
The browser starts on the specified window position on my second screen, but the window is not maximized.
If I delete the '--window-position'-argument, then the browser starts maximized on my primary screen.
One interesting thing is, if I replace '--start-maximized' with '--start-fullscreen', it works. I get the fullscreen-mode on my second screen.
Why is this not working with '--start-maximized'?

This is how I specify the options and start the driver :

```
var options = new ChromeOptions();
options.PageLoadStrategy = PageLoadStrategy.None;
var windowPosition = $"--window-position=1600,-500";
options.AddArguments(
    windowPosition,
    "--start-maximized", 
    //"--start-fullscreen",
    "--enable-automation", 
    "--no-sandbox",
    "--disable-dev-shm-usage", 
    "--disable-browser-side-navigation", 
    "--disable-gpu"
    );
       
options.AddAdditionalOption(CapabilityType.AcceptInsecureCertificates, true);
options.AddUserProfilePreference("download.default_directory", Directory.GetCurrentDirectory());
var driverService = ChromeDriverService.CreateDefaultService();

return new ChromeDriver(driverService, options, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));
```

Comment: I don't think you can control which display the window is opened in. I think it opens in your main display when the driver first starts. After started, it should be opening windows in the same display that is already in use by the driver.

Comment: I think there is a misunderstanding here. It's not that I want a second chrome-window on a different screen to popup, I want the first window, which appears after  chromedriver starts to popup on my second screen and it should be maximized. 
I can control on which position the window should popup and therefore I'm using the x, and y coordinates which belong to my second sreen, so this works. But my problem is, that the window isn't maximized then

Comment: Ok, I see. I actually had the same question years ago, and the answer was the same as my comment above: it opens in the "main display" specified in your operating system settings. To my knowledge there is no web driver setting to change that.

Comment: It's been close to a decade since I researched this topic. I'm going to up-vote. I'm curious to see if anything has changed since then.

Comment: Closest on found on this site is [In a multi-monitor display environment, how do I tell Selenium which display to open a new window in?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3816073/3092298)